# How to print matrix values in octave using printf

Tags: matrix, octave

Suppose I have a matrix A=[1,2] if I try to print it with command

```
fprintf("A ", A)
```

Output

```
A
```

Blank `A` is printed without values?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's:

```
fprintf('A:\n');
fprintf('%f\n', A);
```

You need to specify a valid format specifier when displaying a variable.  Doing `%f\n` will print out a single value per line.  Please read up on how to use format specifiers from the docs: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Formatted-Output.html#XREFsprintf

Comment: Thanks - the key seems to be that it keeps reusing the format string while there are still values in the matrix (read in some unclear order)! And using `"%f "` will print it all on one line, of course.

Comment: @nealmcb You're welcome!  Yes, adding a space within the quotations will separate the values by a space.  It took me a while to get used to how Octave (or MATLAB) prints things vectorized within a single format specifier.